# Sinch - Unable to establish call from web (javascript) to mobile app (android/iOS)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am using Sinch for app to app calls.
Integrated and created iOS and Android apps which are working perfectly fine.

Now I am creating a web app to communicate with mobile apps.
I am able to make call from mobile app to web app i.e. to Javascript
I also successfully achieved web to web call, but I am unable to establish call from web to mobile app.

Following are my findings after debug:
Call In Progress is fired
Call Ended is fired after couple of seconds
Call State is 3 i.e. Progressing
Call End Cause is 1 i.e. Denied

I am following this sample and using sdk version 1.4.8

**This is my calling code:**

```
call = callClient.callUser("myUsername");
call.addEventListener(callListener);
```

Comment: Did you get the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Any Solution. Stucked at same when doing video call from web to android

Answer (score 0):

Here you using the method  "calluser()" so that method will work on web-to-web calling if want to make a call from web-to-app  simply use "callPhoneNumber" method and pass number like this.

var call = callClient.callPhoneNumber('+46000000000');
call.addEventListener(callListeners);

Comment: I didn't meant web to mobile number, instead web app to mobile app

Comment: Then you need to use Rest API of sinch.

Answer (score -1):

I get it working.

Put `supportManagedPush:true` while initializing your JS sinch client on your web.
If app to app call working then web to app will work fine.

Note: This will enable web to call a `android` or `IOS` app while they are not running.(Using `FCM wakeup`)